# WIA 2.0 flatbed scan on ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, wia

I'm writing ASP.Net application that should use network scanner to scan some documents and store them on the server. Scanners will be setup at the server side. I would like to not use Silverlight.
App will be running in IIS 7.5.

I've been able to scan locally and I found out that when I use Application pool identity of server-side local account with admin rights everithing works. But I would like to use an user with only necessary rights.
I've tried to setup DCOM for Wia DeviceManager but I still receive Access is denied error on wia components.

Is there a way to add the user (used in ApplicationPool identity) all the necessary privileges?

Comment: If you're scanning the documents server-side (because that's where the scanners are) - why bother doing it through an ASP.NET.  You can very easily leverage a WinForms application to perform the scan and then update the backend resource directly or through a service...

Comment: I planned to use network scanner that should have had drivers installed on the server and we did not want to install any software on the client side because we needed to store the scanned documents on the server. But the situation changed today and we will be doing WinForms.

Comment: Out of interest - could you detail the process of a client scanning a document...